# Inconsistent Horizontal Spacing with Exp and Log Commands

Tags: spacing, equations

I am typesetting a document in LaTeX and noticed two particularly ugly spacing issues in the equation environment. From the picture below, it is clear that there is inconsistent horizontal spacing at the start of the 'exp' function and after the 'log' function. Of course, inserting a `\hspace` would be one way to fix this, but I would really appreciate a more general solution to add to the document preamble.

[image]

Comment: if you just show an image and don't show what you did how can we suggest a change?. `\log` is a `\mathop` so has different space depending if the following token is a mathord like x or a mathopen like ( other than that I do not see what space you are asking about?

Comment: What you deem to be "ugly" and "inconsistent" is actually a very carefully made design choice -- not just for `\log` and `\exp` but for *all* math operators (more precisely, all objects with status `math-op`). The point of this design choice is that it's helpful to have a thinspace after `\log`, `\exp`, and `\sin` in expressions such as `\log 1`, `\exp 0`, and `\sin\alpha`, but that it's not needed and hence is omitted in cases such as `\log(1)`, `\exp[0]`, and `\sin(alpha)`. (As David notes in his comment, the rule is not to insert whitespace if `math-op` is followed by`math-open`.)

Comment: I'd like to increase the space after the \log in the second case

Comment: Sometimes, just sometimes, the customer isn't right...

Comment: you should put that in to your question, how are we to guess which of the standard tex spacings yiou considered ugly and want to change? You can use `\log\,[1-\exp...` but the spacing will be wrong.